# Raspberry Pi Camera doesn't connect to code

Tags: raspberry-pi, connection

I am an absolute beginner in programming and I tried to make a photo camera that describes the photo with AI (Computer Vision API of Azure from Microsoft). I used the code of Charles Channon that put the instructions on [Hacker.io](https://www.hackster.io/cchannon/raspberry-pi-smart-camera-a8c786).

By just following the instructions I found out that for some reason the code only works in the Linux Terminal and not from the Tronny (keeps saying error `No moduled named 'urllib2'`), which is weird because it's the exact same code? It also only works when I paste it in the `Adafruit_CharLCD/examples` folder, while the instructions tell me that pasting it in the `/home/pi` folder should be sufficient enough, which isn't since the code will then tell that it cannot find the `module named Adafruit_CharLCD`.

So I have sent the code the RaspberryPi (incl. the PiCamera and LCD). It will start to reboot and tell me to "Take a Picture!". After doing this the Screen tells me that it is 'capturing...' the image, but never really does?

I have a feeling that for the average programmer this is a really easy beginners problem that can be solved by correctly pasting the right files in the right folders, but I have tried several folders and renaming things, but it still doesn't work...

Someone who knows how to correctly connect the Raspberry PiCamera to the code with ComputerVision API?

PS. Image of frustration is included

[image: Raspberry Pi hardware]

[image: Photo of my raspberry PI monitor]

Answer (score 0):

```
By just following the instructions I found out that for some reason
the code only works in the Linux Terminal and not from the Tronny
(keeps saying error No moduled named 'urllib2'), 
which is weird because it's the exact same code?
```

I think maybe in Tronny python version 3 is used instead of python version 2 as in Raspberry. Could you check python version in Tronny using this command.

```
python --version
```

As mentioned in [python urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) , it is separated in several smaller modules. So if in Tronny it is python version 3, then you should modify the script header to import correct library

```
It also only works when I paste it in the Adafruit_CharLCD/examples
folder, while the instructions tell me that pasting it in the 
/home/pi folder should be sufficient enough, 
which isn't since the code will then tell that it cannot find 
the module named Adafruit_CharLCD.
```

In the source, there is one import which require Adafruit_CharLCD. So when  you move to other directory, the Adafruit_CharLCD does not exist in current directory. That is why the script is failed to load

```
LCD = None
import Adafruit_CharLCD as LCD
```

To make the script load Adafruit_CharLCD normally, add the following line to the code.

```
sys.path.append("absolute path to Adafruit_CharLCD")
```

Hope that help

Comment: Thank you for your response! Vacation and another deadlines came in between, but ill test it out and let you know! :)